# Root LG. G VISTA

Tags: rooting

I want to root my LG G Vista, hardware Rev. 1.0, Droid version 5.1.1, kernel 3.4.0+, software version VS880PP2. Has several intermittent problems, and I Really wanna figure out what is wrong with it

Answer (score 1):

There are some good apps to Root most of the Phones for example Kingroot is good https://kingroot.net/ install and run it and your phone should be rooted

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to root your device.

The quickest and easiest way is to use the one-click root method, provided by several apps and developers.

- [KingRoot](https://kingroot.net/)
- [TowelRoot](https://towelroot.com/)
- [FramaRoot](https://forum.xda-developers.com/apps/framaroot/root-framaroot-one-click-apk-to-root-t2130276)

Hopefully you'll find that one of these are compatible with your device! I really like KingRoot and find that it's most reliable.

TowelRoot and Framaroot also work well, but I find that they support less devices than KingRoot.

All you have to do is install the app, launch the app and tap on "root" or something of the sort.

Good luck!